# Use of xpathSApply function in R

Tags: r

I am learning R now and faced these errors while using xpathSApply().

```
doc=xmlTreeParse("http://www.w3schools.com/xml/simple.xml")
xpathSApply(node,"//name",xmlValue)
  Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘saveXML’ for signature       ‘"character"’
```

and

```
doc2=htmlTreeParse("http://espn.go.com/nfl/team/_/name/bal/baltimore-ravens")
scores=xpathSApply(doc2,"//li[@class='score]",xmlValue)
Error in UseMethod("xpathApply") : 
  no applicable method for 'xpathApply' applied to an object of class "XMLDocumentContent"
```

How to resolve it.

Comment: You should replace your `htmlTreeParse` by `htmlParse` .

Comment: or add the `useInternal = TRUE` argument to the `xmlTreeParse` call.

Comment: In your first example, we have no idea what `node` is. Even if you used `htmlParse` in the second one, you're missing a closing quote in the XPath attribute expression. Even if you fix that, the ESPN page you are trying to scrape has no elements with that XPath and finally (and most importantly) you are attempting to violate ESPN/Disney's [Terms of Service](http://disneytermsofuse.com/) and also encouraging others to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the `xmlParse` and `htmlParse` functions. Description:

```
‘xmlParse’ and ‘htmlParse’ are equivalent to the ‘xmlTreeParse’
and ‘htmlTreeParse’ respectively, except they both use a default
value for the ‘useInternalNodes’ parameter of ‘TRUE’, i.e. they
working with and return internal nodes/C-level nodes.  These can
then be searched using XPath expressions via ‘xpathApply’ and
‘getNodeSet’.
```

My solution:

```
xml.file <- xmlParse( file = "http://www.w3schools.com/xml/simple.xml")

names    <- xpathSApply( doc  = xml.file
                       , path = "//name"
                       , fun  = xmlValue
                       )

[1] "Belgian Waffles"             "Strawberry Belgian Waffles"  "Berry-Berry Belgian Waffles" "French Toast"                "Homestyle Breakfast"
```

Then, for the ESPN page:

```
html.file  <- htmlParse( file = "http://espn.go.com/nfl/team/_/name/bal/baltimore-ravens")

scores <- xpathSApply( doc  = html.file
                     , path = "//li[@class='score']"
                     , fun  = xmlValue
                     )

list()
```

There must be something wrong with your xpath expression since it is not returning anything :).

Answer (score 0):

Below code worked for me:

```
URL<-"https://www.w3schools.com/xml/simple.xml"
response<-GET(URL)
doc=xmlTreeParse(response,useInternalNodes = TRUE)
root<-xmlRoot(doc)
xml_names<-xpathSApply(root,"//name",xmlValue)
```

you probably missed to set useInternalNodes option to TRUE, when using xmlTreeParse